# Android Attempt to read on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, adapter

I am looking to create a list from JSON content. Here is my adapter code :

```
public class AnswersAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Answer> {

    static Context context;
    static int layoutResourceId;
    Answer data[] = null;

    public AnswersAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Answer[] data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        AnswerHolder holder = null;
        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new AnswerHolder();
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.answerText);
            holder.txtTitle2 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.answerAuthor);
            holder.txtTitle3 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.answerVotes);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (AnswerHolder)row.getTag();
        }
        Answer hold = data[position];
            holder.txtTitle.setText(Html.fromHtml(hold.text));
            holder.txtTitle2.setText(hold.author);
            holder.txtTitle3.setText(hold.votes);

        return row;
    }

    static class AnswerHolder
    {
        TextView txtTitle;
        TextView txtTitle2;
        TextView txtTitle3;
    }
}
```

and I am facing this error :

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String com.example.shivam.stackoverflow.Answer.text' on a null object reference

on this line

```
holder.txtTitle.setText(Html.fromHtml(hold.text));
```

Comment: "How do I fix this?" Make sure that the variable `hold` is not `null`.

Comment: Looks like your **data** is null. Check if you're initializing it properly.

Comment: More precisely, the `data` array has null values in it. (`data[position]` is evaluating to `null` for some `position` value.)

Comment: @Melquiades Unfortunately, `data` cannot be null. If so, a NPE would have occurred in line `Answer hold = data[position]`. So it must be that the array referenced by `data` contains `null` values.

Comment: @TedHopp Do you think this would be fixed if I put a check for each if(data[position]!=null){...} ?

Comment: @ShivamBhalla If you put that check yes your application will not crash but it will not work either, you need to debug and check why your data is becoming null

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Yes, obviously! Thanks for waking me up

Comment: @Keshav1234 I tried using that check and it seems to work fine. Which is understandable, as it would filter out the null values and show only the valid ones. Right ?

Comment: @Keshav1234 Although I am still getting a few empty rows and a few repeated ones.

Comment: @ShivamBhalla The reason for the occurrence of null pointer exception is some variable has become null and you are calling some method on that variable which is meaningless, so that check helps you to get out of this scenario, if null is an accepted value in your case the that check is sufficient or else debugging and checking the reason for that variable becoming null is necessary.

Comment: @Keshav1234 I have used a similar logic in another adapter and it seemed to work fine then. I don't see any scenario when hold would be null :/. Any thoughts on that ? How do I resolve the issue of the missing/repeating rows. ?

Comment: @ShivamBhalla I think hold is not null here, but holder is in that line, please check the value of holder not hold.

Comment: @Keshav1234 Yes I have checked that as well. I don't think that is null either. I even put a check for holder!=null but it still crashes.

Comment: @ShivamBhalla Are you sure it crashes in that line only, clean the project and run it again, check in which line you are getting the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Your `data` array has null values. This is the immediate cause of the NPE, because `hold` ends up as `null` for certain positions. You will avoid the NPE if you test for that, but (as you point out in a comment) your adapter won't behave quite properly. You cannot simply ignore rows that have `null` data values.

As an aside, you should eliminate your `data` member field. The array reference is already being kept by the `ArrayAdapter` superclass. Just use `getItem(position)` whenever you would have used `data[position]`. While this won't address the NPE problem, it will simplify things a bit, as seen below.

You have several options:

1. Find out why certain entries of `data` are `null` to begin with and eliminate the root problem. However, it may be normal (outside the context of the adapter) for `data` to have `null` entries.
2. Revise your `getView` method to set the views in `holder` to some specific values that indicate "data missing"—perhaps blank, perhaps a "no data" message. (In other words, don't simply skip all processing. That is what is causing the combination of blank and duplicate rows.)
3. Revise the constructor to eliminate the `null` entries from `data`. That will result in a shorter list. Some code to accomplish this might be:

   ```
   public AnswersAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Answer[] data) {
       super(context, layoutResourceId, trimmedData(data));
       this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
       this.context = context;
   }

   /**
    * Copy data to a new array that has no nulls.
    */
   private static Answer[] trimmedData(Answer[] data) {
       Answer[] result = new Answer[data.length];
       int n = 0;
       for (Answer a : data) {
           if (a != null) {
               result[n++] = a;
           }
       }
       if (n < data.length) {
           result = Arrays.copyOf(result, n, Answer.class);
       }
       return result;
   }
   ```

   However, this might cause problems elsewhere in your code if you need to maintain a correspondence between the `ListView` position and the original `data` array.

Another aside: you can eliminate your `getItemId()` method; the default implementation in `ArrayAdapter`does exactly the same thing.

Comment: Hi Ted, I was wondering if you could help me with this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30969590/what-is-the-expected-behavior-of-sqlite-crud-operations-after-a-configuration-ch) . It's not one of those "fix-this-for-me" questions, I promise.

Answer (score -7):

Just Change this line .....

```
Answer data[] = null;
```

to

```
Answer[] data = null;
```

Comment: Aren't these two the same ? In any case, making this change doesn't help as the app is crashing anyway.